# Spring data JPA findFirst with where clause (filtering) and order by, internal exception thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I created the following repository

```
public interface DemoRepository extends CrudRepository<DemoEntity, DemoId> {

    Optional<DemoEntity> findFirstByPositionIsNotNullOrderByIdCompositeFieldIdDesc(Long compositeFieldId);
}
```

And the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "demo")
public class DemoEntity {

  @EmbeddedId
  private DemoId id;

  @Column(name = "result_position")
  private Integer position;

  public DemoEntity() {
  }

  public DemoEntity(DemoId id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public DemoId getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(final DemoId id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Integer getPosition() {
    return position;
  }

  public void setPosition(final Integer position) {
    this.position = position;
  }

}
```

And the composite id of the entity class:

```
@Embeddable
public class DemoId implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4782012819350949578L;

  @Column
  private Long compositeFieldId;

  @Column
  private Long compositeFieldIdSecond;

  public DemoId() {}

  public DemoId(final Long compositeFieldId, final Long compositeFieldIdSecond) {
    this.compositeFieldId = compositeFieldId;
    this.compositeFieldIdSecond = compositeFieldIdSecond;
  }

  public Long getCompositeFieldId() {
    return compositeFieldId;
  }

  public void setCompositeFieldId(final Long compositeFieldId) {
    this.compositeFieldId = compositeFieldId;
  }

  public Long getCompositeFieldIdSecond() {
    return compositeFieldIdSecond;
  }

  public void setCompositeFieldIdSecond(final Long compositeFieldIdSecond) {
    this.compositeFieldIdSecond = compositeFieldIdSecond;
  }
}
```

The Spring Boot 1.5.9 (which includes sprint-data-jpa 1.11.9) app starts successfully.

When I call an endpoint which is invoking my new repository method I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.bind(CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:161)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.invokeBinding(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:236)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:157)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:208)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.findFirstByPositionIsNotNullOrderByIdCompositeFieldIdDesc(Unknown Source)
    at io.demo.db.services.PlayerService.hasPlayedRecently(PlayerService.java:56)
    at io.demo.db.services.PlayerService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9179d222.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at io.demo.db.services.DemoService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$139c2adc.hasPlayedRecently(<generated>)
    at io.demo.rest.DemoController.subscribe(DemoController.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

The exception kinda makes sense as the query should return no result in my test, but I would expect to get an empty optional instead of an exception.

Is this a bug or I am mis-using Spring Data? The db is mysql 5.7.

I then tried to upgrade to Spring Boot 2.0 which includes Spring Data Jpa 2.0.5, now the app fails to create the repository during start up:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional io.demo.db.repositories.DemoRepository.findFirstByPositionIsNotNullOrderByIdCompositeFieldIdDesc(java.lang.Long)! Index: 0, Size: 0
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:208)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1309)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetterFactory$CriteriaQueryParameterSetterFactory.create(QueryParameterSetterFactory.java:271)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.lambda$createQueryParameterSetter$1(ParameterBinderFactory.java:138)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createQueryParameterSetter(ParameterBinderFactory.java:140)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.lambda$createSetters$0(ParameterBinderFactory.java:130)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createSetters(ParameterBinderFactory.java:131)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createSetters(ParameterBinderFactory.java:123)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinderFactory.createCriteriaBinder(ParameterBinderFactory.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.getBinder(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:248)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:147)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:268)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:77)
... 61 common frames omitted
```

Still don't get why as the exception is not descriptive.

Thank you.

Comment: can you share your Controller code from where you are calling Repository Method?

Comment: I can, but it's quite a lot of code, do you think it would do any difference? I am just passing a long to my repository method.

Comment: just send the Snippet of particular API where u have called this method, u can also send the screenshot

Comment: made a simpler example which still reproduce it, controller: 
    `@GetMapping("test")
    public void subscribe() {
      playerService.test();
    }`
and service
    `public void test() {
 demoRepository.findFirstByPositionIsNotNullOrderByIdCompositeFieldIdDesc(666L);
  }`

Comment: does findBy, instead of findFirstBy work ?

Comment: I found a solution @Dexter , posted below. Thank you anyway.

Comment: In my case I dont have composite key and its a usual column in the same table. The scenario is when there is no data in the table I get `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException` HTTP 500 ERROR. Do you have any Idea to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, my repository method expects a parameter which is not needed by the query itself. Anyway the exception reported by Spring Data is a bit confusing, I've logged a bug in their bugtracker and they are looking at it: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1281